# Sqllite as graph database

Tags: database, sqlite, graph-databases

I want to use graph database with multithreading program so i was thinking about sqlite, i need to know if it can support graph database and if there is any graph database that support multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a relational database so you will run into some or all of the issues that are commonly talked about when attempting to use a relational database to solve a graph problem. Relational databases don't do a good job at modelling relationships between data nodes and they don't provide support complex navigational queries so this could likely restrict the kinds of "graph" things you will be able to do.

Whether or not SQLite will work for your application will largely depend on the complexity of your graph model and what you want to do with it.

Comment: i would like to have nodes in type of parents and Childs as well as types. my use will be only traversal and updating values in a direct way